# On specific rows, how do I conditionally modify a csv field depending on what is in another field?

Tags: csv, awk, sed, element

I have a csv file name data.csv as shown below

```
"check","small and big","address","plot 25,bangalore","hide"
"check","big and small","ph number","7979797","hide"
"check","small to big","name","jggjgg","show"
```

Now I want `sed` or `awk` command to replace the field next to address in the 1st row to `***` and 3rd row field next to name to `***` and save it in the same csv file.

Sample output should be

```
"check","small and big","address","****","hide"
"check","big and small","ph number","7979797","hide"
"check","small to big","name","****","show"
```

Comment: awk will not trivially process a complex RFC4180 CSV with commas and/or quotes in fields.  You need to use a language where someone has written a RFC4180 compliant CSV library, like Python, Perl, or NodeJS.

Comment: Can you try to make it a little clearer what you want ?

Comment: @user3755420,give me the sample output you required ?

Comment: Hi,input.csv is shown below
"check","small and big","address","plot 25,bangalore","hide"
"check","big and small","ph number","7979797","hide"
"check","small to big","name","jggjgg","show"

i want ouput.csv as
"check","small and big","address","****","hide"
"check","big and small","ph number","7979797","hide"
"check","small to big","name","****","show"

Comment: is there only three lines in that csv file? Did you want blank line between rows?

Comment: There could be n number of lines but I want to modify only 1st row and 3rd row elements after address and name respectively

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk -v FS='",' 'NR==1 {gsub (/.*/,"\"****",$4);} NR==3 {gsub (/.*/,"\"****",$4);}1' OFS='",' file
"check","small and big","address","****","hide"
"check","big and small","ph number","7979797","hide"
"check","small to big","name","****","show"
```

A sorter form suggested by Tom Fenech,

```
$ awk -v FS='",' 'NR==1||NR==3 {gsub (/.*/,"\"****",$4);}1' OFS='",' file
"check","small and big","address","****","hide"
"check","big and small","ph number","7979797","hide"
"check","small to big","name","****","show"
```

And through GNU sed,

```
$ sed -r '1s/^(.*,\")([^"]*)(\",.*)$/\1****\3/g;3s/^(.*,\")([^"]*)(\",.*)$/\1****\3/g' file
"check","small and big","address","****","hide"
"check","big and small","ph number","7979797","hide"
"check","small to big","name","****","show"
```

Comment: Instead of the two identical blocks you could just do `NR==1||NR==3`

Comment: Thanks its working. Can the same think can be done using sed??

Answer (score 0):

Since CSV can be surprisingly hard to parse, I prefer to use a proper CSV parser:

```
$ cat data.csv
"check","small and big","address","plot 25,bangalore","hide"
"check","big and small","ph number","7979797","hide"
"check","small to big","name","jggjgg","show"
$ ruby -rcsv -i -ne '
  row = $_.parse_csv
  row[3] = "***" if ["address","name"].include? row[2]
  puts row.to_csv(:force_quotes => true)
' data.csv
$ cat data.csv
"check","small and big","address","***","hide"
"check","big and small","ph number","7979797","hide"
"check","small to big","name","***","show"
```